# Ten fold time increase between NULL and NOT NULL version of query

Tags: mysql, insert, innodb, myisam

I have two queries that are very similar. They work on the same four tables which are as followed:

```
users_old      => MyISAM 
users_new      => InnoDB
test_attempts  => InnoDB
tests          => MyISAM
```

Basically, a query is run on test, users_old, and users_new which inserts into test_attempts.

This is the first query, it takes about a minute to run, which is long, but not a serious issue. Its main `WHERE` clause contains the clause: `tests.overall_score IS NOT NULL AND` which is later changed in the second version of this query:

```
# this query takes everyone that has taken the wsat-pe legacy and gives them an attempt record
INSERT INTO 
    test_attempts (`user_id`, `test_id`, `score`, `created`, `modified`, `is_deleted`, `meter`, `type`, `status`)   
SELECT 
    users_new.id, 76, tests.overall_score, FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time), FROM_UNIXTIME(end_time), NULL, NULL, 'normal', 'complete' 
FROM 
    users_old, users_new, tests 
WHERE 
    users_old.user_email = users_new.email AND 
    tests.user_id = users_old.id AND 
    users_new.role <> 'admin' AND
    tests.overall_score IS NOT NULL AND
    users_new.id NOT IN (SELECT test_attempts.user_id FROM test_attempts WHERE test_attempts.test_id = 76);
```

This is the second query, it takes about ten minutes to run, which is long. Its main `WHERE` clause contains the clause: `tests.overall_score IS NULL AND` additionally the `SELECT` headers changes `'complete'` to `'canceled'` but these are the only differences.

```
# This cancels the attempts that have been droped by users  
INSERT INTO 
   tests_attempts (`user_id`, `test_id`, `score`, `created`, `modified`, `is_deleted`, `meter`, `type`, `status`)
SELECT 
   users_new.id, 76, tests.overall_score, FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time), FROM_UNIXTIME(end_time), NULL, NULL, 'normal', 'canceled' 
FROM 
   users_old, users_new, tests 
WHERE 
    users_old.user_email = users_new.email AND 
    tests.user_id = users_old.id AND
    users_new.role <> 'admin' AND
    tests.overall_score IS NULL AND
    users_new.id NOT IN (SELECT test_attempts.user_id FROM test_attempts WHERE test_attempts.test_id = 76);
```

They are run on the given tables one after the other. I cannot understand why removing the `NOT` from the first query would cause a tenfold time increase in operation. I cannot run this in my production environment until I understand why this time difference occurs. Since the MyISAM tables use table locking, this would lock our site down for ten minutes and that is not really an option. I'm not sure why this time discrepancy is occurring so any insight would help. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be using MyISAM tables in a production environment for many reasons, including those you've cited.

Comment: @tadman True, but those tables pre-date me, and fixing them is on the list of things to do. That's part of what the `users_new` is about. Any idea what is happening with these queries here? Is there some additionally information that I should also provide?

Comment: It's very hard to tune a MySQL database for both MyISAM and InnoDB since each engine has its own buffers and memory pools. It'd probably be easier to find a solution if you were running InnoDB only. Switching table types can be a bit painful, but the end result is an easier to maintain system. A quick `ALTER TABLE` can flip the engine to InnoDB any time.

Comment: How long does the `SELECT` query take? How many records are returned? What is the execution plan of each query (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`)?

Comment: @RandomSeed Oh man, Explain I totally forgot about that. Good call.

Comment: Would you share your findings?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the 'is not null' qualification in your where clause will result in a full table scan. An explain plan should point this out. If you put a 'default' value in the overall score column to indicate 'no score yet' (e.g. 0 or -1), and add an index on this column and change your where clause to indicate '= 0', your query will be able to process only the matching rows without a table scan.